# firebase app runs on localhost:5000/[projectId]/[region]/app

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-hosting

When i run my firebase app locally, it starts it on this route:

localhost:5000/[projectId]/[region]/app

The problem is, all my post and get requests dont have the [projectId]/[region]/app appended to them.  How can i hit all my routes?